# Storing/reading a function pointer symbol address to/from memory in a bootloader

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, memory-segmentation

I am a newbie when it comes to assembly so this might seem like a simple question.
So, with assembly I am trying to store a memory address to a function into memory like this:

```
my_function:
  mov al, "a" ; Some code
  int 0x10
mov word [0x7e04], my_function ; Storing the address to my_function into 0x7e04
```

And then I want to jump to that memory address after I have read it from memory like this:

```
jmp [0x7e04]
```

However it is not working. Is it because it is only reading the byte 0x7e and not with 04? If so, how would I be able to read a word from memory and not just a byte?

EDIT:
So here is the code that isn't working (yes it is a bootloader):

```
mov ah, 0x0e

mov al,"H"
int 0x10

mov word [0x7e04],my_function
jmp [0x7e04]

my_function:
  mov al, "i"
  int 0x10
times  510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

So I'm compiling it with `nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.asm` and then emulating it with `qemu-system-i386 boot.bin` but then nothing is showing up, and the BIOS interrupt 0x10 is working so I'm a bit confused here why the code does not work

Comment: It should work.  Please post your full program.

Comment: You did not set up `ds` or `cs` and the defaults in qemu do not match your assumption. As a quick and dirty hack you can stick `org 7c00h` at the beginning, but that in turn might not work on other systems so you should really do it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no ORG statement, the program is assembled starting at address 0. The address of “my_function” is 000f, but it is loaded at 7c0f. The JMP instruction jumps to 000f. If CS contained 07c0, this would work. Alternatively, use ORG 7c00 and set CS to 0. (To change CS, execute a far call.)

Comment: Beware that some BIOSes start the boot sector with CS:IP = `0000:7c00`, while others apparently do use `07c0:0000`.  So you can't safely assume *either*.  Normally you only bother to set `ds` and use relative calls, but yeah if you need to use symbols as immediate absolute values for code pointers then your code becomes position-dependent and you need to control `CS:IP` as well.